# wordpress on AWS EC2 ( 2 instances and a load balancer)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am trying to setup a wordpress as part of my learning process.

I have installed wordpress and configured it on two aws instances with a single RDS. It seems to work fine.

Now I am adding a load balancer. How do I make the wordpress that I have installed in two different instances work together under a load balancer? I am not looking for a production level example and would  prefer to do it in a simple way without autoscaling or Elastic beanstalk. TIA

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Load Balancing supports three types of load balancers- **Application Load Balancer**, **Network Load Balancer**, **Classic Load Balancer**. In this case, you have to use **Application Load Balancer**.

**Step 1: Select a Load Balancer Type**

**To create an Application Load Balancer**

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. On the navigation bar, choose a region for your load balancer. Be
   sure to select the same region that you used for your EC2 instances.
3. On the navigation pane, under **LOAD BALANCING**, choose **Load Balancers**.
4. Choose **Create Load Balancer**.
5. For **Application Load Balancer**, choose to **Create**.

**Step 2: Configure Your Load Balancer and Listener**

On the Configure Load Balancer page, complete the following procedure.

**To configure your load balancer and listener**

1. For **Name**, type a name for your load balancer.

   The name of your Application Load Balancer must be unique within your 
   set of Application Load Balancers and Network Load Balancers for the 
   region, can have a maximum of 32 characters, can contain only 
   alphanumeric characters and hyphens, must not begin or end with a 
   hyphen, and must not begin with "internal-".
2. For **Scheme** and **IP address type**, keep the default values.
3. For **Listeners**, keep the default, which is a listener that accepts
   HTTP traffic on port 80.
4. For **Availability Zones**, select the VPC that you used for your EC2
   instances. For each Availability Zone that you used to launch your
   EC2 instances, select the Availability Zone and then select the
   public subnet for that Availability Zone.
5. Choose Next: **Configure Security Settings**.

**Step 3: Configure a Security Group for Your Load Balancer**

The security group for your load balancer must allow it to communicate with registered targets on both the listener port and the health check port. The console can create security groups for your load balancer on your behalf, with rules that specify the correct protocols and ports.

Note

If you prefer, you can create and select your own security group instead. For more information, see [Recommended Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html#security-group-recommended-rules).

On the **Configure Security Groups page**, complete the following procedure to have Elastic Load Balancing create a security group for your load balancer on your behalf.

**To configure a security group for your load balancer**

1. Choose to **Create a new security group**.
2. Type a name and description for the security group, or keep the
   default name and description. This new security group contains a
   rule that allows traffic to the load balancer listener port that you
   selected on the **Configure Load Balancer** page.
3. Choose Next: **Configure Routing**.

**Step 4: Configure Your Target Group**

Create a target group, which is used in request routing. The default rule for your listener routes requests to the registered targets in this target group. The load balancer checks the health of targets in this target group using the health check settings defined for the target group. On the Configure Routing page, complete the following procedure.

**To configure your target group**

1. For **Target group**, keep the default, **New target group**.
2. For **Name**, type a name for the new target group.
3. Keep **Protocol** as HTTP, **Port** as 80, and **Target type** as 
   instance.
4. For **Health checks,** keep the default protocol and ping path.
5. Choose Next: **Register Targets**.

**Step 5: Register Targets with Your Target Group**
On the Register Targets page, complete the following procedure.

**To register targets with the target group**

6. For **Instances**, select one or more instances in your case you should select your **two instances**.
7. Keep the default port, 80, and choose **Add to registered**.
8. When you have finished selecting instances, choose Next: **Review**.

**Step 6: Create and Test Your Load Balancer**
Before creating the load balancer, review the settings that you selected. After creating the load balancer, verify that it's sending traffic to your EC2 instances.

**To create and test your load balancer**

1. On the **Review** page, choose **Create**.
2. After you are notified that your load balancer was created
    successfully, choose **Close**.
3. On the navigation pane, under **LOAD BALANCING**, choose **Target Groups**.
4. Select the newly created target group.
5. On the **Targets** tab, verify that your instances are ready. If the
    status of an instance is initial, it's probably because the
    instance is still in the process of being registered, or it has not
    passed the minimum number of health checks to be considered
    healthy. After the status of at least one instance is healthy, you
    can test your load balancer.
6. On the navigation pane, under **LOAD BALANCING**, choose **Load
    Balancers**.
7. Select the newly created load balancer.
8. On the **Description** tab, copy the DNS name of the load balancer (for
    example, my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com).
    Paste the DNS name into the address field of an Internet-connected
    web browser. If everything is working, the browser displays the
    default page of your server.